# excel - getting data from another workbook file?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

i would like to get data from another workbook
for example I need workbook1 cell a1 to have the sum of column B in workbook2

Is this possible to do without VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, use square brackets around the file name.

Try:

=Sum([workbook2.xls]sheet1!B1:B10)